# hdf5 not supported (please install/reinstall h5py) Scipy not supported! when importing TFLearn?

Tags: python, scipy, tensorflow

I'm getting this error:

```
hdf5 not supported (please install/reinstall h5py)
Scipy not supported!
```

when I try to import `tflearn`. And I think due to this problem my TFLearn code is not working properly?

Answer (score 10):

You need to reinstall h5py using the package manager of your current environment.

http://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html

Answer (score 1):

Download the packages both h5py and curses in this link http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and execute in cmd like this
               pip install filename 
the file must be present in C:\ folder to execute hope it solves.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem with you:

- `hdf5 not supported`

  - You can reinstall `hdf5` to solute
- `Scipy not supported!`

  - First ,you should install [numy+mkl](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) ,after setup successd try import `tflearn` .
  - if you get error again,you can reinstall `Scipy`

This is my solutions.

[image]